# Non isomorphism graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Im confused what is non isomorphism graph

- cant post image so i upload it on tinypic
  Particulary with this example
  [image: my try]

It is said, that this c4 graph on left side is non isomorphism graph.
But this is my try to make it isomorphic, like u might see it on picture

I have idea of non isomorphism graph, with contradiction, that u can for every graph, "squeeze" it, move little left-little right branches and vertices, mark vertices with different numbers, make bijection which shows that u can translate base graph to that derived , the end?

Can u give me some examples with non isomorph. graphs, and explanation that contradict mine?

*all down votes are not welcome, leave comment for discussion if u want to down vote

Comment: The two graphs in your picture are isomorphic. How you draw them is irrelevant. If you want more help you should post more examples of pairs of graphs that you think are or are not isomorphic. You can draw those pictures as text and format them so that they appear verbatim. And please write in complete sentences with complete words. No text message abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks, i ll try to find more examples. English is not my native, but i will try to think twice next time about words

Comment: English as a second language is OK - just do the best you can.  Text message abbreviations are not. Specific examples will really help.

Comment: Also part of question is can u give me some examples of non isomorphic graphs so u can contradict my theory

Comment: I also add that it's perfectly acceptable practice to post in your native language and request a translation by other users.

Comment: Instead of "u", use "you". Using "u" as you would in a text message is not welcome.  Asking questions, without showing your own work, or otherwise failing to include context, are not welcome.  Asking and answering is a "two-way street". You can expect downvotes, and/or votes to close when you fail to honor the expectations of this site.  Whether you welcome such votes or not is irrelevant.  If you do not want downvotes, then *listen and respond to suggestions*, take the site tour, review the site's "help section" (e.g. how to ask a good question), and be respectful of others.

Comment: I'm open for suggestion, and discussion, i think "u" "you" abbrevations , play little role here. I included my try?

Answer (score 6):

Formally, (simple) graphs are an ordered pair $(V,E)$ where $V$ is a set (the vertex set) and $E$ has a set of $2$-subsets of $V$.

So, a $4$-cycle graph really is a pair $(V,E)$ with:

- Vertex set: $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$,
- Edge set: $E=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{1,4\}\}$.

There is no drawing here.

We often draw graphs to make them easier to visualize (and because graph drawings are interesting in their own right).  I might draw the graph like this:

[image]

Someone else might draw it like this:

[image]

These are two different drawings of the same graph.  I.e., the graphs are *equal*.  (Despite being drawn differently.)

---

Graph isomorphism is instead about relabelling.  In this setting, we don't care about the drawing.=

Typically, we have two graphs $(V_1,E_1)$ and $(V_2,E_2)$ and want to *relabel* the vertices in $V_1$ so that the edge set $E_1$ maps to $E_2$. If it's possible, then they're isomorphic (otherwise they're not).

For example:

[image]

These two graphs are

- *not equal*, e.g., only one of the graphs has the edge $\{1,4\}$, so they have different edge sets, but they are
- *isomorphic*, if we swap the vertex labels $3$ and $4$, we go from the left graph to the right graph.

So...

> I have idea of non isomorphism graph, with contradiction, that u can for every graph, "squeeze" it, move little left-little right branches and vertices, mark vertices with different numbers, make bijection which shows that u can translate base graph to that derived , the end?

The part "mark vertices with different numbers" is what isomorphism is about.  If they're isomorphic, you can:

1. Relabel the vertices of one to make it equal to the other.

After which we can

2. Redraw two equal graphs however we like (or even create a video showing how one maps to the other).  But this is about visualization, i.e., making it easier to see and understand.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, @user439345  You can vote up any answer to a question you ask.  You can also accept one answer per question.  So, please do upvote helpful answers, and accept an answer to each question as being the most helpful to you.  To do otherwise (to not vote, or accept) "is not welcome."

Comment: Can't vote, tried. I will wait little time maybe something come better, but this is satisfying and best for know...